# Can't get Kdenlive icon onto desktop

Tags: unity, icons

Have Ubuntu 14.04. loaded Kdenlive from the Software Center. It works from icon on DASH and from Terminal. However, I have no idea how to put icon on desktop. I looked in usr/share/applications-no icon. Also checked /usr/bin/kdenlive. I found the executable, but no icon startup to copy. Would appreciate anything to point me in right direction. Thanks

Comment: `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop --create-new`

Answer (score 0):

If Kdenlive doesn't come with a .desktop file, it cannot be put onto the Desktop. As most programs are advanced, and .desktop files are easy, most programs have them, though I think Kdenlive is one that doesn't. If you want to look into it, it is fairly simple to create your own .desktop file it. Just google it.